# How can i change user role automatically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to change user role once they do some jobs automatically but normal `db.savechanges()` are not working they are not even throwing any error can some fix the issue?

Code used in controller for changing gthe user role in data base is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(PRSV_Login loginData, string ReturnUrl = "")
        {
            string message = "";
            using (PRSVEntities db = new PRSVEntities())
            {
                var dataItem = db.PRSV_Login.Where(x => x.Email == loginData.Email).FirstOrDefault();
                if (dataItem != null)
                {
                    if(string.Compare(Encrypto.Hash(loginData.Password), dataItem.Password) == 0)
                    {
                        int timeout = 20;
                        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(loginData.Email, true, timeout);// pass one more variable admin
                        string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (dataItem.Role == "Admin")
                            {
                                return RedirectToAction("AdminPanel", "Home");
                            }
                            if (dataItem.Role == "Voter")
                            {
                                var isEmail = IsEmailExist(loginData.Email);
                                if (isEmail)
                                {
                                    loginData.Role = "Voted";
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                    Session["username"] = dataItem.Name;
                                    Session["Email"] = dataItem.Email;
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Candidate has Already Voted!");
                                    Session["message"] = "<h1 class=\"display-5 fw-bold sorry\">sorry!</h1><br><p class=\"col-md-8 fs-4\"><b>" +
                                    dataItem.Name + ",</b> <br><br>You can not vote <b>twice or more!</b><br></p>";
                                    return RedirectToAction("Sorry", "Home");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Session["username"] = dataItem.Name;
                                    Session["Email"] = dataItem.Email;
                                    TempData["Name"] = dataItem.Name;
                                    TempData["Email"] = dataItem.Email;
                                    return RedirectToAction("VotePanel", "Home");
                                }   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (dataItem.Role == "Voted")
                                {
                                    Session["username"] = dataItem.Name;
                                    Session["Email"] = dataItem.Email;
                                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Candidate has Already Voted!");
                                    Session["message"] = "<h1 class=\"display-5 fw-bold sorry\">sorry!</h1><br><p class=\"col-md-8 fs-4\"><b>" +
                                    dataItem.Name + ",</b> <br><br>You can not vote <b>twice or more!</b><br></p>";
                                    return RedirectToAction("Sorry", "Home");
                                    
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    message = "Invalid credential provided";
                                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Email-Id/Password");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Email-Id/Password");
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am also using the Identity package.
I am also using a separate class for this role actions which is given below

```
namespace DEE_PRSV_V2_3.MyRoleProvider
{

    public class SiteRole : RoleProvider
    {
        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string Email)
        {
            PRSVEntities db = new PRSVEntities();
            string data = db.PRSV_Login.Where(x => x.Email == Email).FirstOrDefault().Role;
            string[] result = { data };
            return result;
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `db` your `DbContext` object? If so, make sure to call `db.Update(dataItem)` before calling `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Yes, but 'db.update(dataItem)' is showing red squiggly lines under it

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of your method parameter `loginData`, which is not attached to your context. You should change the `Role` of your `dataItem` retrieved from the database.

Comment: But How can I implement that? I am new to C# and ASP

Comment: I am referring to the line where `loginData.Role = "Voted";` should be `dataItem.Role = "Voted";` (line 37 of your code block)

Comment: I have implemented what you said but it shows this '''System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details'''

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET Identity you may inject `UserManager` into your controllers.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

//Action Method

public async Task<IActionResult> Login(...)
{
    // Get current user. You can also use UserManager's 
    // FindByIdAsync or FindByEmailAsync methods.
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

    // Add user to role
    var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "MyRole");

    if(result.Succeeded)
    {
        //Handle result
    }
}
```

Comment: can you say how can I do it without that?